# Gridview on Content page RowCommand does not fire - ViewState?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

The problem I'm having is the RowCommand of my GridView will not fire. I've read through millions of posts, and as a result I think I'm even more confused. So, if you can see what specifically it is I've done wrong here, please point it out.

I did ask a similar question a couple of weeks ago, but I was using a gridview nested in a datalist and using 'Include' Siblings of the EntityDataSource to display the Siblings, which are the many side of the relationship to Referral, it's fine for display, but figuring out Edit Update and Delete was nightmareish. So I've tied to simplify it, but am now stopped in my tracks because I'm losing controls somewhere in the postbacks.

I have a master page with a ContentPlaceholder:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="HomelessStudent.Web.SiteMasterPage" ViewStateMode="Inherit" EnableViewState="True" %> 
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderAgent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

On the Agent page-

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderAgent" runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="SiblingPanel" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Visible="True">       
    <asp:GridView ID="SiblingGridView" runat="server" CssClass="grid"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        DataKeyNames="Id" 
        ShowFooter="true" 
        OnDataBound="SiblingGridView_DataBound" 
        OnRowEditing="SiblingGridView_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating="SiblingGridView_RowUpdating" 
        OnRowCommand="SiblingGridView_RowCommand" 
        OnRowDeleting="SiblingGridView_RowDeleting" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="SiblingName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SiblingName") %>' ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SiblingName") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NewSiblingName" ></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="false">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"  ID="UpdateLinkButton" ></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" ID="LinkButton2"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" ID="EditLinkButton" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="AddNew" Text="Add" ID="AddNewLinkButton"></asp:LinkButton>                   </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" HeaderText="Delete"></asp:CommandField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind (binding data here because show only those siblings that belong to a specific record, ID (Guid) for that record is in the queryString, maybe...

```
            if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["id"] == null)
            {
                if (Session["studentid"] == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("StudentPage.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    referral = GetMostRecentReferral((String)Session["studentid"]);
                    PopulateUI(referral);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                referral = GetThisReferral(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                PopulateUI(referral);
            }
        }
```

Then, in PopulateUI(referral)

```
some stuff...
FillSiblingGrid();
String studentId = ((referral.StudentID).ToString()).Trim();
getSelectedStudentDeatails(studentId);
Session["referralid"] = (Guid)referral.Id;
```

And fill siblings grid-

```
        private void FillSiblingGrid()
    {
        if (referral != null)
        {
            List<Sibling> siblings = new List<Sibling>();
            using (HomelessStudentDataEntities db = new HomelessStudentDataEntities())
            {
                siblings = (from s in db.Siblings
                            where s.ReferralID == referral.Id
                            select s).ToList();
            }
            if (siblings.Count > 0)
            {
                SiblingGridView.DataSource = siblings;
                SiblingGridView.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                int TotalColumns = SiblingGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                SiblingGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                SiblingGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                SiblingGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = TotalColumns;
                SiblingGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No siblings found";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is with ViewState, so I'll add that to my question.

Comment: I spent a small lifetime trying to figure this out. Turns out I had stupidly re-requested the same page in Site.Master, therefore wiping out the ViewState. Once I corrected that, the content page behaved as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem. Enabling the grid view state resolved the problem